# WCF and shared assembly

Tags: wcf

I have a shared assembly between the client and wcf service. Is there a way to detect that the shared assembly is running on the client side or on the wcf side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of functionality does the shared assembly have? Just data/service contracts? Or does it have something else (like utility classes and so forth)?

Basically, there's really no easy way to tell without, certainly not for contracts, and even utility classes would be hard pressed about it (depending on how you use them, checking for the presence of an OperationContext might work).

I'm curious, though... what exactly do you hope to accomplish here? Maybe we can offer suggestions of better ways to get there.

Comment: It's a bit complex to explain the reason behind. There's too much history into the project i'm currently working on and it's only a temporairly solution. We are going to re-write the whole app. But the OperationContext should work. Thanks!